# Docker in wsl2 cannot ping Hosts' Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm having problem where my ubuntu ran with WSL2 cannot resovle a domain, but is able to ping the internet using ip address. That is it won't work if I issue

```
ping google.com
```

but, it would work if I ping 142.251.163.102 (google's IP). I can ping 8.8.8.8, but if include

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

in my /etc/resolv.conf, it still won't resolve a domain.

THings I have tried from my research:

I also tried putting Hosts'

1. disable auto generation of /etc/resolv.conf in /etc/wsl.conf

   [network]
   generateResolvConf = false
2. Use my host's Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter in /etc/resolv.conf
3. convert the distros to wsl1, and copy /etc/resolv.conf from wsl1 to /etc/resolv.conf in wsl2
4. use the dns server from windows in /etc/resolv.conf

What's weird is that

1. if I switch to WSL1 domain would resolve
2. If I stayed in the office using wired connection, item 3 above would make things work

I saw people are saying to try disabling firewall because the firewall is blocking connection, but it's not possible because I don't have admin access.

Anyone knows How I can resolve domain in WSL2?